# Where are all the locations where command history is saved on linux server

Tags: linux, bash, history

I know that the history can be seen by just running the command 'history' but I am wondering where else commands may be stored.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the location of the (only) history file of your shell using `echo $HISTFILE`. Most likely, this is what you are looking for.

Single commands may store additional information. For example, `sudo` may store the commands executed as root in the system log. If you run the mysql CLI, it would store its history (by default) in `~/.mysql_history`.

Answer (score 1):

By default it's stored in `~/.bash_history`

Answer (score 1):

Command history is a shell-specific feature stored on a per-user basis. The `history` command displays what the current instance has in memory.

The `history` command takes options `-r`, `-w`, and `-a` to read from, write to, or append to (respectively) a default history file, which is `~/.bash_history` or the name stored in the `HISTFILE` variable.

Generally speaking, though, the shell could be configured to read and write history to an arbitrary file; there's no way to know where history could be stored without being familiar with a particular user's shell configuration files or scripts.